# jquery fading in, load page, fading out, load page again

Tags: jquery, load, fade

I have a page that randomly takes 8 pictures to show.
They have to fade in and out so I would like to use a jquery timer to accomplish this.
I have made some code that fades the page in, but then it disappears and fades in again. I would like to let it fade out to, but not immidiately. There had to be a pause of 3 seconds between it.

this is my code so far:

```
    $('#footerShuffle').hide().load('includes/footerShuffle.php');
    $('#footerShuffle').fadeIn('slow');

    setInterval(function(){
        $('#footerShuffle').hide().load('includes/footerShuffle.php');
        $('#footerShuffle').fadeIn('slow');
    },5000)
```

and this is the page where you can see what is happening: http://bouwenenwonen040.nl/  in the footer you can see the fading images.

Does someone know how to make it

Comment: It's because you have two `.hide()`s and fade ins... Why? If you just want a delay around the second part, wrap it in a `setTimeout`: `var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(/*PUT IT HERE*/, /*delay in ms*/);`. If you want it to fade instead of disappear change the second `.hide` to `.fadeOut`

Answer (score 0):

Well change the hide to fadeout, and then change the 5000 to 3000. Next time when you copy a code from the source try to put more  effort in it to understand what you are copying.